# What is a Matrox GPU and why does my university's UNIX server have one?

Tags: linux, unix

I was interested in the specs of the UNIX server my university provides for students, so I ran [screenfetch](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch). Here's the output:

```
                                               user@unix4.university.edu
              `.-..........`               OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5 Maipo
             `////////::.`-/.              Kernel: x86_64 Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
             -: ....-////////.             Uptime: 9h 1m
             //:-::///////////`            Packages: 3796
      `--::: `-://////////////:            Shell: bash 4.2.46
      //////-    ``.-:///////// .`         CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2680 v2 @ 40x 3.6GHz [61.0°C]
      `://////:-.`    :///////::///:`      GPU: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2
        .-/////////:---/////////////:      RAM: 8290MiB / 64215MiB
           .-://////////////////////.
          yMN+`.-::///////////////-`
       .-`:NMMNMs`  `..-------..`
        MN+/mMMMMMhoooyysshsss
 MMM    MMMMMMMMMMMMMMyyddMMM+
  MMMM   MMMMMMMMMMMMMNdyNMMh`     hyhMMM
   MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMyoNNNMMM+.   MMMMMMMM
    MMNMMMNNMMMMMNM+ mhsMNyyyyMNMMMMsMM
```

All I can find about Matrox GPUs is their wikipedia page which says that the G200 was released in 1998. Why would my university have them in a modern server (CPU was released in late 2013)?

Comment: Do you think a UNIX server should have what? A Nvidia card? For what games exactly? No, a server just needs something to display text mode most of the times. I don't remember but people back in 1998 were already using graphical desktops, with Windows 98? A Matrox G200 is way more powerful than needed for a server.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia A lot of students use this server for CS homework and I'm in a class using Tensorflow. I was hoping there would be some CUDA GPU available to play around with.

Comment: I am sure there are CUDA special processors, just not on that server. They cost a LOT of money (and no, what you likely know as CUDA is not even funny - NVidia does special cards, wait until you get access to a server with 6 of those for Tensorflow work... each eating a 2080ti for breakfast).

Comment: And modern - I am buying EPYC servers right now. Crap VGA. "Modern"? Sure. Jsut as given in the answers and my comment , that is the VGA to rely on for installation ;) On board, cheap, works. Same in most modern machines. Add waht you need then.

Comment: Note for mobile app user who only sees ASCII art on this question: scroll to the right, or tap the code block to see the server's information!

Comment: I seem to remember that was the kind of graphics card found in the BeBox back in the good days. Which was pretty nice at the time being (though before most visitors of this site were born...).

Comment: @peterh The E5-2680 v2 (Ivy Bridge) was released late 2013 and is still orderable from Intel.

Comment: @user71659 Sorry, it was an estimated value from the kernel version (and from the Matrox).

Comment: Are you really sure this is not a virtual machine?

Comment: @trognanders Hypervisors don't emulate a Matrox (and nobody would virtualize one either, if at all possible). They either have their own GPU driver or they expose a generic VESA SVGA card.

Comment: @user71659 I knew about the paravirtual drivers but never really thought about the *comes with everything* SVGA driver. You are definitely right though, the Matrox card does not seem to be a popular emulated device.

Comment: @trognanders: I have several physical servers from Dell and HP here, and [most of them use G200](https://imgur.com/a/XGRUMXH), attached under the BMC's own PCI bridge as user1908704 has mentioned. (Although the oldest one uses ATi ES1000.)

Comment: @grawity That is an excellent data point. I like your hypothesis that it is associated with the remote console view administration stuff. Seems that this is definitely a server running directly on the hardware.

Comment: @peterh: Well, it's RHEL. Once they pick a kernel (v3.10 is from mid-2013), they stick with it through the entire 7.x series, even if it means having well over 800 backported patches on top.

Comment: @TomTom there is a lot between no GPU at all, and a  server-dedicated card. Specially for homework, something around a 1070 or even a 750 can give you decent speeds, without too many limitations (from which, by the way, one can learn a lot). For example, I do research in ML, and my machine has two 1070Ti, but I have access to beefier machines when I need it (that is not that often).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

General-purpose servers don't need a modern GPU - just enough to show a medium-sized console desktop. They mostly deal with regular CPU computing and networking.

Matrox G200 VGAs, however, are commonly used on servers due to their integration with a [baseboard management controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) (BMC, also known as iLO, iDRAC, or the IPMI).

This management controller acts as an independent system with its own operating system and lets the server's administrator remotely connect to the console display & keyboard – they can see the BIOS screens, restart a server even if it's completely frozen, even start it from full power-off. For these tasks, the controller must know what the graphics adapter is displaying right now.

So **I would guess** that the old Matrox video adapters are used for this because they store the video buffer in system RAM (instead of their own VRAM) and use a sufficiently simple data layout that the BMC can decipher it without needing arcane knowledge about the GPU's internals, nor without any help from the main OS.

(Or perhaps the opposite – as mentioned in comments the G200 is usually *built into* the BMC, possibly giving the BMC completely direct access to the G200's video buffer.)

But even if the server was built for GPU computing, I assume it wouldn't have an "all-in-one graphics card" as PCs do, but instead a set of *dedicated* compute-only GPGPUs (e.g. from nVidia) for the heavy work – and still the same Matrox VGA for the console.

Comment: I suspect it's more likely that, when Matrox became irrelevant to the video card market, they sold or licensed the G200 design for whoever produced the BMC to include in the BMC chip, integrated with the remote administration functionality.

Comment: " it probably wouldn't have a single "graphics card" GPU as PCs " - no. Servers would have a single GPU on board. Not seen a server board without on board GPU for ages. You then add Nvidia special cards as needed. Same here, The G200eR2 is on board. It is a chip, not a card.

Comment: @TomTom: Right. I was reluctant to even call G200 a "GPU" because I was under the impression it didn't have much 3D processing or acceleration at all (which it apparently does have).

Comment: There's no G200 chip, it's implemented inside the BMC, which already speaks PCIe.  I had assumed it was actually a reimplementation of the register-level interfaces (in the way that all GPUs can do basic VGA without being based on something from 1985), but it turns out Matrox do licence the G200 IP to chip designers.

Comment: In addition the drivers for the G200 and similar Matrox "chips" are old and stable and rock-solid. That too is important on a server.

Comment: @R.. - "when Matrox became irrelevant to the video card market" ... Matrox have never become irrelevant to the video card market.  They've simply become *specialised* -- AIUI, they are the market leaders in producing video cards for systems that need to support very large numbers of monitors.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan: If only the whole BMC also were rock-solid, too...

Comment: @grawity, I had a proper G200 in my PC back then. It was never meant for a gamer, but it could do a reasonable 3D and the best 2D acceleration in class, all while having much less issues in general than the contemporary nVidia and ATI. Basically, it was a very high quality card, both in hardware and software, with modest 3D performance being the only drawback. Another anecdote: a company I worked for _had_ to use Matrox cards on modern PCs because they still offered all the legacy modes such as 16 colours (not 16 _bit_ ;) at high resolution.

Answer (score 36):

That Matrox G200eR2 is not a separate video card.
It is a chip directly integrated into the server motherboard.
It is cheap, very reliable, easy to integrate and provides excellent text (console) display ability and decent 2D graphics ability.
Is is also so well known that just about every Operating System for Intel hardware has driver support build-in for it.

The only purpose for a VGA card there is to get a basic console display that you can use for Bios setup and initial installation of the server. After that you will probably only ever access the server remotely.
It doesn't have to be a good VGA card. You are not going to be gaming on it. But it is a major blessing if it works out-of-the-box with whatever OS you are going to install on the server.
And that is all you need and want in a server.

Matrox chips have always been very popular for this purpose and this particular one was still used in 2014 in new Dell servers and probably in some other brands as well.

Comment: Actually, on most servers the (graphics and text) display support is there only for operating systems like Windows. The management interface almost invariably supports BIOS setup via serial port (usually accessed through the BMC via the network) and OSes such as Linux can do a full install and subsequent operation with a serial console, meaning that you never have to use the "video" console display at all. This allows remote installation of a bare machine you've never even touched, though the same can often be done via remote video over network.

Comment: `You are not going to be gaming on it.` - speak for yourself, i made automation programs for online mmorpg games and had it running 24/7 doing rudimentary mundane but beneficial tasks, on servers.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson, I'm not sure about that... A VGA output is still the "default" interface, which every device has. With it, you can connect completely different devices to a single KVM switch (network-based or not), and for the really simple cases you don't need to touch the management controller at all. Regardless of the OS, not having a VGA output and a keyboard connector would be a bit of a nuisance.

Comment: @ilkkachu VGA is the "default" for "PC" ISA hardware, but never was for most other server systems (Sun, etc.). Anyway, if you find it convenient to use a KVM or whatever, sure go ahead with that, but straight serial has a lot of advantages (e.g., faster, esp. over bad networks, you can log all the output, more easily automated, ...). As for the management unit, __do not ignore it unless you don't plug in its network port__. Even when well-configured they are incredibly insecure, and an unconfigured one invites a system takeover by anybody who can send it packets.

Comment: Oh, and I can say from extensive experience that, for Unix servers in typical professional environments, not having VGA is not in any way a nuiscance. In fact, having it, and having to ensure the system doesn't use it, can be more of a nuisance. (You don't think all those cloud servers that Amazon and Google run use real or emulated video output, do you?)

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson, I don't think Sun servers are that common nowadays (or have been for a while, even). I do wonder about ARM-based systems and such, but I'd still be willing to bet a couple of drinks that most places that have anything called servers, including all small offices and such, exclusively have x86 "PC"-like machines. Google, FB and Amazon don't really compare, they may well have fully custom hardware, and even they did have unnecessary devices on their servers, they only need to figure out disabling them once per machine type, not once per server...

Answer (score 16):

> Why would my university have them in a modern server (CPU was released in late 2013)?

Because a server does not need a high-performance GPU.
And by the way, Matrox had good *Multi-Monitor* graphics cards long before ATI/AMD and NVidia had them.

So the decision had probably been logical by the time of purchase.

Comment: Very logical *and* very cost effective, I assume, given the chip's age.

Comment: +1 for old trusty Matrox'es...